# Open a specific screen of my application using the firebase password reset link

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm working on password recovery with firebase on my application in React Native. It works in a basic way, a link is sent to the email and the user changes the password in a window that opens in the browser (this is the default firebase).

What I want to do is my own new password form, so that when I open the link that is sent to the email, my application opens on that screen, someone has done it?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

[Deep Linking with React Native](http://ihor.burlachenko.com/deep-linking-with-react-native/)